# Avoid path redundancy in Gitlab CI include

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, include, gitlab-ci

To improve the structure of my Gitlab CI file I include some specific files, like for example

```
include:
  - '/ci/config/linux.yml'
  - '/ci/config/windows.yml'
  # ... more includes
```

To avoid the error-prone redundancy of the path I thought to put it into a variable, like:

```
variables:
  CI_CONFIG_DIR: '/ci/config'

include:
  - '${CI_CONFIG_DIR}/linux.yml'    # ERROR: "Local file `${CI_CONFIG_DIR}/linux.yml` does not exist!"
  - '${CI_CONFIG_DIR}/windows.yml'
  # ... more includes
```

**But** this does not work. Gitlab CI claims that `${CI_CONFIG_DIR}/linux.yml` does not exist, although the documentation says that variables in include paths are allowed, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-ciyml-file.

What also didn't work was to include a file `/ci/config/main.yml` and from that include the specific configurations without paths:

```
# /ci/config/main.yml
include:
  - 'linux.yml'    # ERROR: "Local file `linux.yml` does not exist!"
  - 'windows.yml'
  # ... more includes
```

**How can I make this work or is there an alternative to define the path in only one place without making it too complicated?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be implemented at the moment, and there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30686) at the moment in the backlog.

Also, with the documentation saying that you could use `variables` within `include` sections, those are only for predefined variables.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that this would be the answer, but hoped for something else. At least I do know, now, that people are working on this. Concerning to the docs, you made me realize that I didn't pay enough attention to the punctuation, namely the colon, so I thought I'm only limited in the names for my own variables.

Comment: The example given indicates it isn't only predefined:
OUT_PATH and PACKAGE_PATH were both dynamically generated from a predefined, but it could be assumed the predefined could also be replaced with a string and you could get it working; just making that note.

Answer (score 0):

See if [GitLab 14.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/08/22/gitlab-14-2-released/#use-cicd-variables-in-include-statements-in-gitlab-ciyml) (August 2021) can help:

> ### Use CI/CD variables in include statements in .gitlab-ci.yml
>
> You can now use variables as part of `include` statements in `.gitlab-ci.yml` files.
> These variables can be instance, group, or project CI/CD variables.
>
> This improvement provides you with more flexibility to define pipelines.
> You can copy the same `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to multiple projects and use variables to alter its behavior.
> This allows for less duplication in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and reduces the need for complicated per-project configuration.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_2/pipeline_include_variables.png -- Use CI/CD variables in include statements in .gitlab-ci.yml]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variables-with-include) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219065).

---

And with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#configurable-maximum-number-of-included-cicd-configuration-files) (May 2023):

> ### Configurable maximum number of included CI/CD configuration files
>
> The `include` keyword lets you compose your CI/CD configuration from multiple files. For example, you can split one long `.gitlab-ci.yml` file into multiple files to increase readability, or reuse one CI/CD configuration file in multiple projects.
>
> Previously, a single CI/CD configuration could include up to 150 files, but in GitLab 16.0 administrators can modify this limit to a different value in the instance settings.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#maximum-includes) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/207270).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Now, I'm looking forward for my organization to upgrade to 14.2 (we're currently at 14.0) to try this out.

Comment: @bjhend OK. Don't forget to update this page if this actually does work.